Opted-out phone number not appearing in list of opted-out numbers in AWS SNS Sandbox
I'm using AWS SNS Sandbox and recently opted out of a phone number by replying "STOP" to a message. I expected this number to appear in the list of opted-out numbers, but when I try to fetch the list using listOptedOutNumbers, I get a null response.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Used the AWS SNS Sandbox to send a message to my phone number.
Opted out by replying "STOP".
Called the listOptedOutNumbers function, expecting the opted-out number to appear in the list.

If this is actually the fault of groovy or grails, please provide a [mre]. Otherwise remove the tags to get more focused answers.
